# How to compile A SDL c++ program?

Tags: c++, sdl

command line input :

```
g++ sdlm.cpp -IC:\SDL2-2.0.10\include -LC:\SDL2-2.0.10\lib\x64 -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
```

main file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
using namespace std;
#undef main
bool run=true;
SDL_Surface * image;
SDL_Surface * winsur;
SDL_Event *e ;
SDL_Renderer *ren;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if(!SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING))
  {
    cout<<"working"<<endl;
    cout<<SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING)<<endl;
    SDL_Window * win;
    SDL_Renderer * ren;
    SDL_Surface *sur;
    win=SDL_CreateWindow("window",20,20,1280,600,0);
    ren=SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    winsur=SDL_GetWindowSurface(win);
    if(ren==NULL)
    cout<<"failed to render";
    SDL_Event *e;
    e=new SDL_Event;
    bool run=true;
    image=SDL_LoadBMP("chessboard.bmp");
    if(NULL==image)
    {
      cout<<"cannot load the surface"<<SDL_GetError()<<endl;
      return 0;
    }
      while(run==true)
      {
        SDL_PollEvent(e);
      if(e->type==SDL_QUIT)
      {
        break;
      }
      SDL_BlitSurface(image,NULL,winsur,NULL);
      SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(win);
      SDL_PumpEvents();
      }
      cout<<"exited loop";
  }
  else
  {
    cout<<"Something is wrong"<<SDL_GetError()<<endl;
    cout<<SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING)<<endl;
  }
  SDL_FreeSurface(image);
  SDL_FreeSurface(winsur);
    return 0;
}
```

I keep getting the Error:-

> sdlm.cpp:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `SDL_Init`
>   sdlm.cpp:(.text+0x5d): undefined reference to `SDL_Init`
>   sdlm.cpp:(.text+0xb2): undefined reference to `SDL_CreateWindow`
>   sdlm.cpp:(.text+0xd0): undefined reference to `SDL_CreateRenderer`
>   [...]

Comment: You probably have libraries for wrong architecture. What's in your `lib\x64` directory? Are there any other places where you have `libSDL2.dll.a`?

Answer (score 0):

You have a bunch of *linker* errors. You need to link all the object files you compile together to produce the final executable.

You may want to use a *build system* like [CMake](https://cmake.org/), [SCons](https://scons.org/) or [GNU Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) to express dependencies in your code, rather than trying to do everything by hand. But if you insist on doing it "by hand", remember that compilation of a C++ program consists of several phases; first is *preprocessing*, then comes *compilation*, then *assembling* (usually done as part of the previous phase by your compiler) and then the final phase is *linking* all the compiled objects together.

Comment: Preprocessing , compiling and assembling , aren't they all handled by the gcc/g++ itself ?

Comment: @AnimeshPathak • yes, gcc/g++ are toolchain drivers and the preprocessing, compiling, assembling, and linking are handled by them.  But you need to provide all the relevant files to the gcc/g++ toolchain drivers.

Comment: @AnimeshPathak Often, yes. Sometimes, no. It depends on how you invoke the compiler. In this case you obviously forgot to link something (since you have unresolved symbols).

Answer (score -1):

You first of all need to check that all the file directories are mentioned in your command. If the error persists, a nifty trick which *shouldn't* really be used is to take out `-l SDL2main` and add at the top of your `main.cpp` the line `#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED`. Also, you are mixing 32-bit and 64-bit: `-l mingw32` isn't really compatible with `...\lib\x64` if it's actually 64-bit. Choose **one** system and stick to that.

Comment: I was told you have to include -lming32, doesnt matter if you are using 64 or 32 bit .

Comment: nope, `-l mingw32` tells it to use the 32-bit toolchain, which requires 32-bit libraries

Comment: @lenerdv it isn't. 32 bit is forced by `-m32`. `libmingw32` is just a library name, nothing special about it.

Comment: @keltar is it? afaik, `-m32` tells it to build a 32-bit program, `-l mingw32` tells it to use the 32-bit libraries

Comment: @lenerdv `-lmingw32` is "link with libmingw32". That's all that is. Thing is just called "mingw32" for whatever reason, there is a separate branch that is "mingw32-w64" which can target both 32 and 64bit windows. Confusing stuff, but it's everywhere in windows - win32, system32, ...; it never about architecture anymore.

Comment: @keltar I knew that 64-bit systems could run 32-bit programs as they are an 'upgrade', but not that this could bring so much confusion... thanks, anyway